# What are the risks to have a Paypal Clientid in Angular client side app?

Tags: javascript, angular, paypal

I'm using [this Paypal intergration for Angular](https://enngage.github.io/ngx-paypal/) with their template. I'm having no trouble, no bugs, no errors, but I've got a security concern. My client id is visible in the javascript bundle of the angular app.

How dangerous is it and what measures could I take in this case?

I've tried angular environments and dotenv, but then realized that no matter what the client id ends up in the bundle.
I've also tried to contact Paypal, but it took 3 days for them to reply to my question, and there was no actual answer, they just redirected me to this website and their forums.

```
// some code
 private initConfig(): void {
      this.payPalConfig = {
      currency: 'EUR',
      clientId: 'sb',
      createOrderOnClient: (data) => <ICreateOrderRequest>{
        intent: 'CAPTURE',
// some more code
```

[Here](https://enngage.github.io/ngx-paypal/) is the full template if one is interested.

Comment: Is there a system where you put the URL of javascript origins?  I don't know much, but in google console you should specify the origins, so they only accept your client_id if is from your urls...

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are only showing your clientId... so that would only let people to... create buttons to pay you. So the risk is that some "hacker wannabe" wants to use that and create a button in another website, that make people pay you... I don't see a problem with that. It's perfectly safe.

Comment: @RodrigoButzke, could you please elaborate more on that? And what is a url of javascript origins?

Comment: @Ruslan To use Google apis, such as OAuth you must create a project that will contain the client_id and secret_id, the client_id is free to everyone know since you have to define the URL that will use the API with your credentials, and https://docs.moodle.org/36/en/OAuth_2_Google_service in the image "Credentials", there is a field where you define the origins of JavaScript code that are a accepted by the API. I don't know about PayPal, just asked about it because there is something in Google Console...